# MYSQL Product listing grid

Tags: php, mysql

So i am trying to pull product data from a database and have it listed out in a nice grid. I have got everything to work and its layout is very nice apart from one issue, the image URL isnt pulling properly:

```
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $rows[] = $row;

foreach ($rows as $row){
    $etitle = $row['title'];
    $eprice = $row['price'];
    $eurl = $row['prod_url'];
    $eimage = $row['image'];

    echo ('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url("' . $eimage . '");">
                    <a href="' . $eurl . '"></a> 

                    <div class="card-image-rating">');
                echo ('£' . $eprice);
                echo ('
                    </div><!-- /.card-image-rating -->
                </div><!-- /.card-image -->

                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2><a href="' . $eurl . '">');

    echo $etitle;

    echo ('</a></h2>
        </div><!-- /.card-content -->

        <div class="card-actions">
            <a href="' . $eurl . '" class="card-action-icon"><i class="md-icon">favorite</i></a>
            <a href="' . $eurl . '" class="card-action-btn btn btn-transparent">Show More</a>
        </div><!-- /.card-actions -->
    </div><!-- /.card -->

</div><!-- /.col-* -->');

} ?>
```

In the source code and on page everything look good apart from their being no image. The column in the database has a URL of the image location in it but in the source code it appears to be removing the / from the path.

Any help would be amazing.
Thanks,

Comment: Is your value of image variable contains full path to the image. If not then you need to prove the path to the image directory and put the file name of the image from database. First check what your are getting from the DB on image variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your script, I noticed something goes wrong

```
<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url("' . $eimage .'");">
```

you use double quotation marks in style section

your html will look like this

```
<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(" ");">
```

which is shouldn't be like that.

you have to use Apostrophe inside style, since u use quotation mark for style

your html should like this

```
<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(' ');">
```

here, an example for you
https://jsfiddle.net/have_full/kass6ukr/